# Overflow has no background

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an `article` styled like with this class:

```
.stretchedToMargin {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

This is fine: the article takes always *at least* the whole vertical space. For articles longer than the screen, a scrollbar is shown.

But, for articles extending further than the screen, when I need to scroll to view the content, the background is not set. The `article` is split between a part with the right background and a part with the wrong background.

How can I force my `article` to be actually as high as the content, *but* at least as high as the viewport?

### EDIT

Adding an example: http://jsbin.com/UvasEBik/1/
An the corresponding screenshot:

[image: partial background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use min-height: 100vh which is 100% of the viewport height. So the article would be at least 100% of the viewport height.

Comment: Thanks, but even with `min-height: 100vh;` the overflow is not styled.

Comment: You need to add overflow: auto; to .stretchedToMargin in your css